# problem with O_DIRECT IO with aligned stack buffer

Tags: c, io, alignment

The following code fails when the buffer is on the stack, but succeeds when it's allocated on the heap. I tested it on RHEL 5.3 with a Raid drive. Is it possible to use O_DIRECT with stack buffers?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <malloc.h>


#define K 1024
#define ALIGNMENT (4*K)
#define RDSIZE (16*K)
#define BLOCKSIZE (512*K)

int main()
{
    int flags = O_RDONLY |  O_LARGEFILE;
    int n = 0;
    int fd = 0;
    char* buf = (char *) memalign(ALIGNMENT, BLOCKSIZE);
    //char buf[BLOCKSIZE] __attribute__((__aligned__(ALIGNMENT)));

    assert(((long)buf) % ALIGNMENT == 0);

    fd = open("test", flags | O_DIRECT);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("file open");
        return -1;
    }


    n = read(fd, buf, RDSIZE);

    if (n < 0) {
        perror("file read");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);

    close(fd);

}
```

UPDATE: Same code when compiled with Intel CC succeeds.

Comment: +1 for a great question.  I assume the assert() succeeds and the open() fails?  What is perror() printing?

Comment: Side note: `#define ALIGNMENT (4*K)` and so on. Otherwise you're headed for trouble, because the C preprocessor is token-based. See [C FAQ 10.1](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html).

Comment: good catching the macro issue, this is a quick and dirty reproduction of the problem, so pardon my bad style

Comment: open succeeds. read fails when using the stack buffer with perror printing invalid argument.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't give 3 argumets to open(), as you don't use O_CREAT

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? Stack alignment was traditionally buggy and may still be for alignment values larger than 16.

Comment: OK, this certainly looks like a compiler bug.  Your program works fine for me on Ubuntu Natty (gcc 4.5.2), CentOS 5.5 (gcc 4.1.2), and Suse 11 SP1 (gcc 4.3.4).  If you want to debug your compiler, compile with "-S" to produce foo.s and then post it somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Check your stack size 512K is quite a lot.

Comment: it's a 64bit machine. it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is gcc misaligning `buf`, try this portable version instead:

```
char x_buf[BLOCKSIZE+PAGE_SIZE];
char *buf = buf + (PAGE_SIZE-1 & -(uintptr_t)x_buf);
```

Comment: that's not the problem, the buffer is aligned properly as the assert passes.